# How to install red5 media server via ssh using maven on my linux centos machine?

Tags: linux, ssh, maven-3, red5

Hi i have installed java, maven and set all environment variables needed for java and maven, 
just need guidance on how to build red5 from source
please see this https://github.com/Red5/red5-server#build-from-source

My specs :

> Apache Maven 3.2.2 (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e;
>   2014-06-17T09:51:42-04:00)   Maven home:
>   /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.2
>
> Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
>
> Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.79.x86_64/jre
>
> Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "linux",
>   version: "2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Answer (score 0):

For Java 1.7, I don't known if compatible, Red5 is old and need serious update. I'm running a Red5 server (0.8.0) on CentOS 7, 1GB Ram, with Java 1.6.

Pre-install;

```
yum -y install java-1.6.0-openjdk java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://apache.cs.utah.edu//ant/binaries/apache-ant-1.8.2-bin.tar.gz
tar zxvf apache-ant-1.8.2-bin.tar.gz
mv apache-ant-1.8.2 /usr/local/ant
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ant/bin
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/classes.zip
echo 'export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/ant' >> /etc/bashrc
echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java' >> /etc/bashrc
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/ant/bin' >> /etc/bashrc
echo 'export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/classes.zip' >>/etc/bashrc
yum install subversion
```

Red5 install;

```
cd /usr/local/
svn export http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/tags/0_8_0/
mv 0_8_0 /usr/local/red5
cd red5
ant prepare
ant dist
```

For running Red5;

```
cd /usr/local/red5/dist
sh red5.sh
```

If you got error about JAVA memory;

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms32m -Xmx128m"
```

And the script for autorun;

```
#!/bin/sh
# Startup script for Red5 flash streaming server on RedHat/CentOS (cPanel)
# chkconfig: 2345 95 55
# description: Red5 Flash Streaming Server
# processname: red5

PROG=red5
RED5_HOME=/usr/local/red5/dist
DAEMON=$RED5_HOME/$PROG.sh
PIDFILE=/var/run/$PROG.pid

# Source function library
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

[ -r /etc/sysconfig/red5 ] && . /etc/sysconfig/red5

RETVAL=0

case "$1" in
 start)
 echo -n $"Starting $PROG: "
 export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms32m -Xmx128m"
 cd $RED5_HOME
 $DAEMON >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
 RETVAL=$?
 if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then
 echo $! > $PIDFILE
 touch /var/lock/subsys/$PROG

fi
 [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && success $"$PROG startup" || failure $"$PROG startup"
 echo
 ;;
 stop)
 echo -n $"Shutting down $PROG: "
 killproc -p $PIDFILE
 RETVAL=$?
 echo
 [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/$PROG
 ;;
 restart)
 $0 stop
 $0 start
 ;;
 status)
 status $PROG -p $PIDFILE
 RETVAL=$?
 ;;
 *)
 echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
 RETVAL=1
 esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Enjoy your RED5 Flash Media Server

Source: https://forum.ovh.com/showthread.php?83099-TUTO-Installer-serveur-RTMP-(Flash-Server)-avec-Red5

Comment: thank you brother but i used the pre build releases ;)